# Element type is invalid in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am a beginner to react js. While building a small project I faced this

```
error :: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I did not understand what does it mean by this . Can you please help me out

Comment: You are either not exporting/importing your component correctly, or you are trying to render an object instead of a property. You should add some code so we can tell you exactly what's wrong

Comment: Without seeing the code that causes an error, it is generally impossible to give a high quality answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I need to see your code to tell the problem.
However, I hope this helps you

This error occurs for the following reasons:

1- Mixing up default and named imports when importing a component.

2 -Forgetting to export a component from a file.

3- Incorrectly defining a React component, e.g. as a variable instead of a function or class.

[See more details](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-element-type-is-invalid-expected-string-but-got#:%7E:text=To%20solve%20the%20error%20%22Element,functions%20or%20classes%20as%20components.)